# TimePickerDialog won't show

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a simple `TimePickerDialog`. When the user clicks on the `editText` box then the time picker appears. Can you please help? The below code won't show the dialog. Thanks for the help.

```
package com.example.myproject;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener;

import android.widget.DatePicker;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private OnTimeSetListener myTimePicker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void show(){

        Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
        int Sysday=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int Sysmonth=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int Sysyear=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        int Sysmin=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int Syshour=c.get(Calendar.HOUR);



             new TimePickerDialog(this, myTimePicker , Syshour, Sysmin, false);


    }



}
```

---

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="mytext"
        android:onClick="show"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
public void show(){
```

To

```
public void show(View v){
```

And

```
new TimePickerDialog(this, myTimePicker , Syshour, Sysmin, false);
```

To

```
(new TimePickerDialog(this, myTimePicker , Syshour, Sysmin, false)).show();
```

Comment: Did you apply both changes?

Comment: works perfectly thanks. I think I replied before the second change was added

Answer (score 1):

I think you should explicitly call `Dialog.show()` method

```
TimePickerDialog dialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, myTimePicker , Syshour, Sysmin, false);
dialog.show();
```